# How do I change the order of the videos on YouTube in a playlist that I have created?

Tags: youtube

Suppose I created a playlist on YouTube and added 50 videos to it. Now I want to swap video 30 and video 31, is there an easy way?

There seems to be one way but very complicated: you can move a video to the top or to the bottom, so you can move video 30 to the top, and then video 31 to the top, and now video 31 is before video 30. And now, move the previously video #29 to video #1 one by one "to the top", and they will be in the order you desire, but it is really complicated.

Answer (score 2):

When you hover over the video, on the left side you should see a vertical bar with either dots or dashes and your mouse pointer should change shape to a grabbing hand. Grab the video and move it to your desired location (up or down).
[image: bar with dots]